# How to build request body using pojo and and lombok builder in rest assured

Tags: post, pojo, rest-assured

Trying to build Rest-assured request body with POJO and lombok builder

I have created the POJO objects, not sure how to build the request body for below code

```
{
    "con": {
        "ipAdr": "1.11.222",
        "site": "ghyt"
    },
    "cred": {
        "login": {
            "user": "abc",
            "pd": "xyz"
        }
    },
    "view": "qwe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add preferred JSON serializer to classpath or as a dependency in your Maven/Gradle project. As of RestAssured 4.0.0 you can try:

- FasterXML's Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
- Google's GSON (https://github.com/google/gson)
- Apache's Johnzon (https://github.com/apache/johnzon)

Here's an example of POJO with lombok's @Builder annotation:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MyPojo {

  private String view;
}
```

And RestAssured post request:

```
MyPojo pojo = MyPojo.builder()
    .view("some-value")
    .build();
RestAssured.given()
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .body(pojo)
    .post("http://www.example.com");
```

There's a lot of information on this topic on RestAssured documentation page - https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#object-mapping

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I didn't make the question clear. I was wondering if I can use Lombok builder as I have dynamic payload to send in the request body. Yes I will be using Jackson for json serialization and de-serialization.

Comment: @Kav so i worked with lombok to reduce boilerplate in POJOs and used those POJOs in rest assured payload. you can still use lombok's builder to create POJOs and then pass those to request payload

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for your json is:

````
public class Con {

public String ipAdr;
public String site;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Cred.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

@Data
public class Cred {

public Login login;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

@Data
public class Example {

public Con con;
public Cred cred;
public String view;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Login.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

@Data
public class Login {

public String user;
public String pd;

    enter code here

} ```
````